# Trigger Worksheet_SelectionChange after change in certain column

Tags: excel, vba

I want `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange` to trigger after entering a value in a cell within column E. However, after pressing Enter, I need to click back on the cell for the macro to execute.

I have attempted `If Not Intersect` along with `Application.EnableEvents` to trigger my macro.

This is the code in VBA, I am getting the value in column E, once it has the same value as column A, it will fill in timestamp for that row.

```vb
Sub recordTimeStamp()

' Declare variables
Dim Barcode As String
Dim CartNo As String
Dim Row As Long
Dim Timestamp As String

' Get the barcode from the scanner
Barcode = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Application.ActiveCell.Row).Value

' Get the current timestamp
Timestamp = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm AM/PM")

' Loop through all the rows in column A
For Row = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' If the barcode matches the cart number in a row
If Barcode = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value Then
    
    ' If the particular row of column E is not empty, fill in 
column E else column F
    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 5).Value) Then
        ' Fill in the timestamp in column E
        ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 5).Value = Timestamp
    Else
        ' Fill in the timestamp in column F
        ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 6) = Timestamp
    End If
    
    ' Remove the value in the dynamic (selected) row in column E
    ActiveCell.ClearContents
    
    ' Select the row with the timestamp
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1).Select
    
    ' Exit the loop
    Exit For

End If

Next Row
End Sub
```

This is where I call it:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    recordTimeStamp
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Hitting enter should trigger the event since the selection changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should use the Change-Event, not SelectionChange (`Worksheet_Change`).

For example, when you enter something in Cell E1 and press Tab, Focus will be set to F1. The Change-Event will have `target` set to E1 (because cell E1 was changed). In this trigger you can react on the changed value of this cell.

*After* this event, the SelectionChange-Event will be triggered, but `target` will be F1 because now this cell has the focus. In this trigger, you neither know which cell had the focus *before* nor if or if not something was changed in that cell.

Comment: Interesting, that certainly beats going back one step, seeing what changed and redoing the change :o

Comment: Yes, I make some changes and insert the whole procedure into the Change event, and using Target and Me. for the adjustment, it works now. Thank you so much for the info